# Can i import a site (plugins, database, images) etc. Into an existing wordpress multisite?

Tags: multisite, import

So i have 1 external website that i need to add to an existing Wordpress multisite. However I i dont want to do anything to harm or change the existing network of sites. The external site has its own theme (Divi) thats a WYSIWYG so just downloading and uploading theme doesnt work. Was going to use WP All in one migration for this.